# How can I make a for statement have an else

Tags: php

I have a databse that has food reviews on it, and I want to show if a food is vegetarian or not.
I want to add a echo "No"; but I don't know how.

I've tried using else, but it doesn't show.  I've also tried `<?php for($x=1;`

Here is my code:

```
<p>Vegetarian: <span class="sub_heading"><?php for($x=0; $x < $find_rs['Vegetarian']; $x++)
                    {
                        echo "Yes";
                    }
                        ; ?></span></p>
```

I want it to show no if it is 0 and yes if it is 1

Comment: I'm curious why this is in a loop. What's the value of `$find_rs['Vegetarian']`? I feel like all you need is an if statement of `if ($find_rs['Vegetarian'] == 1) echo "Yes"; else echo "No";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p>
    Vegetarian: 
    <span class="sub_heading"><?= $find_rs['Vegetarian'] ? "Yes" : "No"?></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply add an `if` conditional inside of your loop that checks against the value of `$x`:

```
for ($x=0; $x < $find_rs['Vegetarian']; $x++) {
    if ($x == 1) {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else if ($x == 0) {
        echo "No";
    }
    else {
        echo "x wasn't either 0 or 1 -- x was $x";
    }
}
```

Note that the final `else` condition will output the value of `$x` due to the use of double-quotes.

Comment: For some reason, this returns No for the ones that are vegetarian (value is 1) and is blank for those that aren't.

Comment: I tried the other answer and the same thing happened.  What have I done wrong?

Answer (score -1):

if the condition only 2, just using if else statement,

```
<?php
for($x=0; $x < $find_rs['Vegetarian']; $x++){
     if($x == 1){echo 'Yes';}else{echo 'No';}
}
?>
```